# What is wrong with this code for visual studio code highlighting?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, yo

I'm new in visual studio code language creation, and I tried to make my own syntax highlighting for my custom language using *yo code*. In my `tmLanguge.json` file, I got this code, but I don't work and it doesn't highlight anything at all. Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

When I tried it only with the `"comments"` object, it worked well...

Thanks

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "OP-RANDS++",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#comments"
        },
        {
            "include": "#numbers"
        },
        {
            "include": "#blocks"
        },
        {
            "include": "#basecalls"
        },
        {
            "include": "#outin"
        },
        {
            "include": "#defines"
        },
        {
            "include": "#maths"
        },
        {
            "include": "#others"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "comments": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name":"comment",
                    "match": "^\u005c?.*"
                }
            ]
        },
        "numbers": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.numeric",
                    "match": "\u005cd|\u005c\u005c\u005cd"
                }
            ]
        },
        "blocks": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "emphasis",
                    "match": "{|}|[|]|(|)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "basecalls": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "keyword.control",
                    "match": "\u005c.|\u005c|"
                }
            ]
        },
        "outin": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "entity.name.function",
                    "match": ";|,"
                }
            ]
        },
        "defines": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "variable.name",
                    "match": "~|`|^"
                }
            ]
        },
        "maths": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "keyword.operator",
                    "match": "+|-|*|/|%"
                }
            ]
        },
        "others": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "keyword.other",
                    "match": "'|$"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.opp"
}
```

Comment: You realize that what your doing basically is creating a Grammar in JSON right? So every Match property is a Regular Expression pattern. To access the patterns you need use either the settings.json file colors property, or an even better option is to just define your own theme using a `foobar-color-theme.json` file with the `"tokenColors": []` property.

Comment: Really to help you further you would need to focus on somthing more specific about the problem your having, or give us some sort of details about what you have tried, and what you expect to happen,  and what is happening.